# C++ - Can't for the life of me figure out what I have wrong here (dynamic arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to create an array of integers from a single integer here (this is for a homework assignment to create a larger integer). All the couts here are me trying to figure out why it doesn't seem to want to print the integer. Here's my constructor:

```
MyInt::MyInt (int n)
{
   maxsize = 1;

   if (n > 0) { 
   // Divides the number by 10 to find the number of times it is divisible; that is the length
      int i = n;

      while (i > 1) {
         i = i / 10;
         maxsize++;

         cout << "\nMax Size is = " << maxsize;
      }
   }

   intstring = new int[maxsize];

   for (int j = (maxsize - 1); j >= 0; j--) {                   
   // Copies the integer into an integer array by use of the modulus operator
      intstring[j] = n % 10;
      n = n / 10;

      cout << "\nj = " << j;
     cout << "\nintstring[j] = " << intstring[j];
  }
}
```

I wrote a test show function to test out the constructor and a few operator overloads I did real fast, and I got a segmentation fault. I wasn't sure if it was from this constructor or the conversion from const char*, so I started trying it with just a conversion from int (i.e. MyInt(12345). Here's the show function:

```
void MyInt::testShow() {
   for (int i = 0; i < maxsize; i++) {
      cout << intstring[i];
   }
}
```

Now here's what it's printing:

```
Max Size is = 2
Max Size is = 3
Max Size is = 4
Max Size is = 5
j = 4
intstring[j] = 5
j = 3
intstring[j] = 4
j = 2
intstring[j] = 3
j = 1
intstring[j] = 2
j = 0
```

Here's my destructor as well, not sure if this is causing the problem?

```
MyInt::~MyInt ()                                                
// Destructor
{
   delete [] intstring;
}
```

The couts just... stop there. Doesn't print anything else. Can't figure it out for the life of me. I've diagrammed it and I don't THINK I go out of bounds in the constructor, but I could be wrong. I also tried commenting out every other function except the constructor and the destructor, but the weirdness persists. If you guys need more info let me know.

edit: Header file:

```
class MyInt
{

public:
  MyInt (int n = 0);           // first constructor
  MyInt (const char* c);

  MyInt& operator++ ();
  MyInt operator++ (int i);
  MyInt& operator-- ();
  MyInt operator-- (int i);

  ~MyInt ();
  MyInt (const MyInt& mi);
  MyInt& operator= (const MyInt& mi);

  void testShow();

private:
  int* intstring;
  int maxsize;
};
```

And my main function:

```
int main () {

  MyInt a(12345);

  a.testShow();
}
```

Comment: I'll edit in my header file and int main(), but that should be all that it's reliant on.

Comment: *Should be* all? Test it before you post it.

Comment: Everything else is commented out.

Comment: So, you want binary coded decimal? ok. Let's correct `maxsize`: `maxsize = 1;for(int tmp = n;tmp > 9; tmp /= 10) maxsize++;`. That makes maxsize at least 1 even for n==0. BTW: Shall `MyInt` only deal with non-negative numbers? then use unsigned int please.

Comment: That's more efficient than my code, but it's still failing to print past "j = 0" for some reason.

Comment: I copied/pasted the code, added `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout;`, and got more output: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee4a75976131f214

Comment: Can you add a `cout << "\nFinish\n";` at the end? BTW: My calculation is not more efficient, it's more correct...

Comment: Here's a guess: did the program you were actually testing finish and `exit` or return from `main`, or did it go back to check for more input or something?

Comment: Proposed change: `Add cout << "\n";` at the end of your constructor. See and wonder: It outputs everything... (even before, you just had no separation)

Comment: @aschepler: I have #include <iostream> and using namespace std;, tried resetting Putty and I'm still getting the same oddity using G++. Tried using "using std::cout;" instead, still the same error. I'm fairly positive it finished, because it returns me to SSH after printing j = 0.

Comment: I tried it and get more output, but weird characters at the end.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think you solved it. It was just printing into the next line, which was covered by the prompt... that's slightly embarrassing.

Comment: Ha! Yes. @user1888527, I'm guessing you use zsh.

Comment: @SørenDebois: tcsh, actually! I SSH into my college's machines to do programming work.

Comment: Ah. Funny. At my machine, your program behaves normally on bash, sh, and tcsh, but zsh chokes on the non-newline last output.

Comment: @SørenDebois: Just another quirk to computers, I guess. I'm discovering a lot of quirks as my programming education continues!

Comment: What about my comment regarding `maxsize`? And are you sure you want to save your number big-endian? What about using `unsigned`, as you currently have weird behavior for negative numbers?

Comment: @Deduplicator: My professor told us to initialize to 0 if there are negative numbers, and he provided myint.h along with the first constructor, so I'm assuming he wants us to accept ints regardless of sign and then correct it?

Comment: Ok, but then start with `if(n<0) then n=0;`, as currently you get weird behavior. What about the store order and the calculation of `maxsize`? Please test with number 42 to see the error.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Aaaah, I see. That makes `maxsize = 3`, correct? I wasn't sure why yours was more correct, but now I've adapted it to my code. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, your original did so, while mine got 2. Would have worked (probably, depending on the rest of your program), but been bigger than wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to keep it strictly to the size of the integer to make things easier on myself, but the specifications are lax enough to allow up to five extra spaces in the array.

Comment: Better not get in the habit of using such latitude (unless it makes things significantly easier or faster). So, now test with `-1`. Have Fun.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Works great! Thanks! Now to fix that segmentation fault (ends up I had accidentally declared `maxsize` again in the conversion constructor for `const char*`...)